# Feature Request : Visual Post Editor

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, markdown-preview

Posting in StackOverFlow isn't visual. Users have to fetch what it will look like and have to post. So, please add a feature of visual editing (Like Wordpress).

Comment: There is a preview below the post. Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Editing and Previewing isn't comfortable at all. It is boring in some case.

Comment: "Boring"? Is SE supposed to be enthralling? I'm good with something that works. For those of us who don't use Wordpress, could you give a more concrete example of what you want?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting idea. That said, I don't think anyone will seriously consider investing developer time to it without first seeing at least a couple of examples where the current editor is inadequate, and where visual editing would significantly improve the situation.

Comment: Are you making feature requests just for the sake of it st this point? You’ve asked like 5 questions on various metas over the last few days, and they’ve all been downvoted, and you don’t seem to display any internalization of the feedback you’ve received in subsequent posts. By your own admission, you’re new to StackExchange, you find it confusing, you’re learning the ropes, so how about you **hang around a while and get a sense of how things *do* work** before making more suggestions for radical changes?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the desktop version already allows `ctrl+b` for bold and `ctrl+i`for italics. That seems automatic enough!

Answer (score 4):

For me the current editor and preview are enough.

I do understand you won't be a markdown master from the start, but you don't need to. The toolbar helps you to learn the markdown language, and even if you don't learn the syntax, still the preview will show you what the end result was.

You seem to be asking for a WYSIWYG editor. There is no added value for such editor. Often I find those working not too well.